# why must we initialize DS And ES registers in MS-DOS?

Tags: assembly, dos, cpu-registers, x86-16, segment

in MS-DOS ,Why  the initialization of the DS and ES registers must be done manually by the programmer, although it's operating system responsibility to initialize these registers.

why mustn't we do this for CS and SS registers ? Which feature of MS-dos Leads into this?

Comment: What's the context? Of course, MS-DOS initializes these registers for what the *OS needs*. If you are writing an application and need to use these registers, they must be set for what your *application needs* (which are generally different) and you must save the prior register values before you return to the OS. The `cs` is the code segment and must necessarily be what is needed by your application for it to execute. And the stack is managed system-wide by the OS, so `ss` must be set properly as well for your application. `ds` and `es` don't have such central roles.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a choice of the OS designer.

DOS is a minimal OS, so it does the minimum possible. The CS and SS registers *must* be set. Without CS set for you, your code could not run. SS must be set because DOS uses one stack for everything. Interrupts are using the stack over 30 times per second even while your program is running. (This is why you must turn off interrupts when modifying SS.) The other segments are needed only if your program uses them (and it's certainly possible to write code that doesn't), so DOS isn't concerned.

Actually in DOS versions I remember (and it's been many years so this could be wrong), DS and ES were set equal to CS, which is what you want for very small programs with at most 64k of code+data+stack requirement.

Comment: Indeed DS and ES are initially set to the PSP segment which is the same as CS and SS for .COM files but different for .EXE files. Some linkers insist on the fact that at least DS is initialized to the PSP segment.

Answer (score 0):

EXE files might not have a single or other special segment to default init DS at all, and have multiple static data segments.  IOW all globals are FAR.

The first load of DS is then to the segment of the first variable that needs to be loaded.